# Replace style in Notepad++ with Regex

Tags: regex, replace, html-table, notepad++

I need remove all style tag in the `<td>` with notepad++
for example

```
<td colspan="2" style="background:#eee;">1234</td>
```

change to

```
<td colspan="2">1234</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need this ?

`search : style="(.+)"`

```
replace with : ""
```

P.S. please check **Regular expression** (mode)

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should make a new np++ "Tab" and select the language as css and type:

```
td {
    background:#eee;
    colspan = 2;
}
```

and link to to the html with

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need replace all tag with regex